# Why cant i combine javascript and php in my code?

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (and escape newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines)

I am quite new to the concepts of Javascript/jQuery and PHP. I have been using PHP implemented in Appserv for two weeks now to get data from a modbus device and store it in a csv file. Now i want to plot the data using jQplot. I am trying to write a simple program to first see if i can implement php and javascript code together in html. This is a code that i have written in html and uses both javascript and php.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>This is a script</h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var out = <?php echo "Hello"?>;
    //var out = "Hello"
    document.write(out);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When i run this code in the browser ( I use google chrome with windows 7) I only get the heading "This is a script". However if i remove the line with the php code and uncomment the next line

```
var out = "Hello";
```

then the code prints the output with "Hello" like its supposed to. Why is this?

Comment: OT: `document.write` is **evil**.

Comment: Have a look at the source code that your PHP outputs. Should be obvious then.

Comment: Have you looked at the sourcecode PHP generated? Have you looked into the error console?

Comment: @Bergi I tried it with json_encode and normal integer values but it dint work still

Comment: @KarthikSai: Really? Could you please post the produced HTML (or link to your demo)? Do you get any JS errors?

Answer (score 5):

You need add quotes around your PHP tags, like this:

```
var out = "<?php echo "Hello"?>";
```

Otherwise after PHP has parsed the file and output it it'll output like this:

```
var out = Hello;
```

... notice you're missing the quotes, JavaScript won't like that.

Comment: I added the quotes like you said. It dint work yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to enclose your php code, as you give the value to your out variable :

```
    var out = <?php echo "Hello"?>;
```

Should be :

```
    var out = "<?php echo "Hello"?>";
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think this is where the issue comes from. :)

Edit : Looks like some people were faster than me anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with Ben Everard and Eddy Yuansheng Wu with a slight modification

This works:

```
var out = "<?php echo 'Hello'?>";
```

This doesnt work

```
var out = "<?php echo "Hello"?>";
```

Reason: using double quotes will consider it as end of string and js stops its functionality.

Comment: "Reason: using double quotes will consider it as end of string and js stops its functionality" Not true, remember, PHP is back end, and thus the PHP script will be output `Hello`, nothing more.

Comment: Guess you are right! Thanks Ben.